# How do I store and read hashed passwords for a locally run POS python program?

Tags: python, authentication, bcrypt, pos

I am using bcrypt, but I dont know what file formats to use and whats the best course of action. Did research on different sites but I didnt really find a good solution or an answer for bcrypt. I just need to store passwords locally, no recovery or email needed.
I hope someone understands me, thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always look at [`sqlite3`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html) as a database within the file system. If this seems too complicated for you then you could look at using a [JSON file](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html).

If you are only handling 1 hash at a time then a text file would do but it seems you would need multiple so either SQLite or JSON would suit your needs.